# Mark a certain cell in a html table - (voting table)

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, voting

I am searching for days to get my problem solved I got different ideas but none seems to work as expected.

My problem: I have some mysql tables which look like this:

[image: MYSQL Tables]

What I want to do with this mysql-table is, post it as a html-table
which should look something like this:

[image: output table]

My problem is that I don't know the number of users, who are voting for an answer and I even don't know the number of answers.

I just want to mark the table cell with an x, in which the user had chosen the answer.

This is the code that comes the nearest to my intended goal.

```
$sql = "SELECT voting_user.*, voting_user_answer.*, voting_answeren.* FROM
voting_user, voting_user_answer, voting_answeren WHERE  
voting_user_answer.thema_id = $thema_id AND voting_user.user_id = 
voting_user_answer.user_id AND voting_answeren.answer_id = 
voting_user_answer.answer_id";

$i=0;   
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr><th>answer-ID</th><th>answer</th><th>user</th>";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {


echo "<tr><td>".$row["answer_id"]."</td>
<td>".$row["answer_option"]."</td><td>".$row["user_name"]."   
</td></tr>";
$tableRows[$i]=array("answer_option"=>$row["answer_option"],
"user_name"=>$row["user_name"], "cross"=>"x");
$namen[$i]=$row["user_name"];
$answer = Array
(
"answer_option" => $row["answer_option"]
, "test2" => "x"
);


$i++;
$counter=$i-1;
}
echo "</table>";


$resultMatrix = array();

foreach($tableRows as $resulting) {
$from = $resulting['answer_option'];
$to = $resulting['user_name'];
$cross = $resulting['cross'];

$resultMatrix[$from][$to] = $cross;
}

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>', '#', '</th>';


foreach($namen as $user_name) { 
echo '<th>', $namen[$i] ,'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach(array_keys($resultMatrix) as $answer_option) { 
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>', $answer_option, '</td>'; 
foreach(array_keys($resultMatrix[$answer_option]) as $user_name) { 
echo '<td>', $resultMatrix[$answer_option][$user_name], '</td>';    
}

echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

I would be grateful for even the slightest hints.

### edit

My html output so far, looks like that
[image: html output so far]

But I want it to look like this
[image: desired html output]

The upper table is just for clarification, so that you can see how the voting results are looking.

My problem is that I don't know how many users are voting and how many answers the user can chose from. 
That will differ from poll to poll. So I can't use a static table to mark the cell.

Comment: You are putting the users as columns of a table , now when you will have 1000 users , what will happen ? Secondly , the two tables from which you are taking the values seems to be same , what is the difference between those two tables ?

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you explained the shortcomings with your current solution and showed the html it generates.

Comment: edited my post, I hope I provided the needed information